# Accept() timeout setting on Windows XP SP3

Tags: go, windows-xp, blocking, i386

I faced a critical issue while using go1.9.2 windows/386 on Windows XP SP3.

The Accept() blocks forever, even if I set a timeout using SetDeadline(), until the program exits.

I consider it critical because I can't stop listeners when I need to. Additionally, conn.Read() blocks forever as well, but I didn't include it to the example to make is simpler.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8888")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    tcplistener := listener.(*net.TCPListener)
    tcplistener.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 2))

    fmt.Println("Listener started")

    go func() {

        defer func() {
            tcplistener.Close()
            fmt.Println("Listener closed")
        }()

        for {

            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
                return
            }

            conn.Write([]byte("OK\n"))
            conn.Close()

        }

    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)

    fmt.Println("Exit")
}
```

Terminal output:

```
Listener started
Exit
```

In contrast, when I run this program on Windows 7 under VirtualBox (on the same Windows XP SP3), Accept() successfully unblocks after a timeout period.

Terminal output:

```
Listener started
accept tcp [::]:8888 i/o timeout
Listener closed
Exit
```

Comment: If Windows XP SP3 is still a supported platform (I haven't checked), then I would open an issue rather than asking here.

Comment: @JimB According to the Go website Windows XP SP 2 is the minimal supported Windows version. https://golang.org/doc/install#requirements

Comment: @JimB Okay, I've opened an issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23375

Comment: Just tried to compile it on a previous stable version (go1.8.5 windows/386). The issue is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution: **reinstall** Windows XP SP3.

I've tried to check how the app works on another installation of Windows XP SP3 and Windows XP SP2 and found that there were no issue.

Obviously, this means my XP works in a different way. Unfortunately, I have no ideas what is wrong.